# Codename Theme Builder

Tags: codenameone

Codenameone Theme Designer shows a black window beside the themeGui Configurator, I think I would see the effects on my changes on that black space,
To move this black space:
1 run the program, the simulator will show up on top of this black space,
2 Move the simulator, to a location in the screen that hides most of it, luckily I use two screens, so I move it to the other screen
3 close your running program,
4 start theme Gui Configurator, you will see the black screen showing at the new location you left your new program,

Anyways, what to do with this screen? thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug due to the simulators desktop mode. If you change the simualtor to a regular skin mode then launch the designer it should work correctly. We need to release an update to the designer but due to the CEF migration we're delaying it as much as possible so the update will include the CEF support. Otherwise the designer might break for a lot of people.

Comment: Blackscreen is gone, thank you, However, should I expect to see a phone skin while designing? I only see the regular Desginer that shows the theme. thank you

Comment: No. This is a specific bug related to desktop mode and the designer